# apps script - mimic prompt response with html selector

Tags: html, google-apps-script, prompt

I am quite satisfied with how work Buttons and prompts with google app script, but they are no options such as multichoice selectors.
I tried to do it through an html output, but once the html output is displayed, the script ends. The output html is correctly displayed, but i'd like the script to return the selected value when i click on "submit".

Here is my gs code, the popUp_car is the one that i execute :

```
function popUp_car() {
  //Page_car_selection is the name of the html file
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page_car_selection');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Output html - title');
}

function runsies(values){
  Logger.log(values);
}
```

and here is my html :

```
<label for="car">Select a car brand :</label> <br/>

<select title="Selection list" id="car" standart>
  <option value="no_choice">Click here to select</option>
  <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="Submit" class="action" onclick="form_data()" >
<input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />

<script>
function form_data() { 
  var choice=document.getElementById('car').value
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().testt();
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().runsies(choice);
  google.script.host.close();
}
</script>
```

Here is how the box look if it helps in any way [html output screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K10MS.png)

Edit - to clarify what i am searching for : alerts and prompts do **suspend server side scripts**, and give the possibility to **use the user response** server-side. This is exactly what i'd like to do, but with a custom selector - more specificaly to attribute the user selection to a variable within the popUp_car function in order to use it server-side-.
I assume i cannot use custom html within an alert. I just found out about **Card Service** class. Maybe cardService Action / actionResponse might do the trick ?

Comment: Remove `google.script.host.close()`  from `form_data`.  And note that `google.script.run` are asynchronous so `runsies` will start before `testt` finishes.  And where are your success handler callback functions?

Comment: @Agalirian When I have replicated your script, I get this [Uncaught TypeError](https://imgur.com/a/RnxMHha) on the console, thus `runsies` function never starts because `testt` (not existing as a function on your provided script) causes an error & stops the process. Also just to clarify, when you say **_`"i'd like the script to return the selected value when i click on "submit"."`_**, do you mean you want the `runsies` Apps Script function to **log** the selected value from the `Output html`?

Comment: @IrvinJayG. i deleted the `testt` part that -indeed- doesn't refer to anything anymore. 
To clarify, i'd like the `popUp_car` function to **return** the submitted outpout, so i can assign it to a variable and use it within a function.

@TheWizEd as i said above, the `test` part has been deleted. Can you tell me more about success handler functions ? This is basicaly pieces of codes i found there and here and are obviously missused. This is the first time i use `.run.withSuccessHandler()`.

Comment: @Agalirian a success handler callback function handles the value being returned by a server-side function to be shown on your html file while being viewed. For more details about it, you may check Google's official [sample](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#index.html_2).

Answer (score 0):

### Suggestion

***[UPDATED]***

Since your main goal is for the `popUp_car` function to return the submitted output & be able to assign it to a variable to be used within a function, here's what you can try:

1. Remove the line `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().testt();` on
   your html code as it causes an error that instantly breaks the
   process before the
   `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().runsies(choice);` can run.
2. Also remove the `google.script.host.close();` as seen on the tweaked HTML code below.
3. Change the line `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().runsies(choice);` to `google.script.run.popUp_car(choice);`. I believe you don't need to use `.withSuccessHandler()` as you will only pass the selected value from your html selection to a server-side function.
4. Tweak your `popUp_car` script as seen below:

### Tweaked Apps Script

```
function popUp_car(value) {
  //Page_car_selection is the name of the html file
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page_car_selection');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Output html - title');
  if(value ==null)return; //skip the process while value is null
 
  //Example code: Set the selected value to cell A1
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.getRange("A1").setValue(value);

  //Close the Output html after the selection
  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<script>google.script.host.close();</script>');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(output, 'Closing...');
}
```

### Tweaked HTML Code

```
  <label for="car">Select a car brand :</label> <br/>

  <select title="Selection list" id="car" standart>
    <option value="no_choice">Click here to select</option>
    <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>

  <input type="button" value="Submit" class="action" onclick="form_data()" >
  <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />

  <script>
  function form_data() { 
    var choice=document.getElementById('car').value;
    google.script.run.popUp_car(choice);
  }
  </script>
```

### Sample Demonstration

- Say `Opel` is selected on the Output HTML:

> [image]

- After clicking the `Submit` button, `popUp_car` function runs,  processes the selected `value` (in my sample code, it sets the value to cell `A1` on my test sheet) & then closes the html dialog:

> [image]

- The HTML dialog then auto-closes after clicking the submit button

> [image]

Comment: @Agalirian Please let me know if there's anything missing or unclear. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, i think i get how it works. I called back an other function in order to use it server-side and it looks like it does the trick.